# Word hyperlinks not opening asp.net files

Tags: asp.net, html, ms-word

I have some Word files which need to have hyperlinks.  The hyperlinks go to an htm file with an anchor, but that htm file isn't provided via a direct url for security reasons.  Rather it is linking to a ashx handler file that retrieves the file and does an response.write to show the html file in the browser.  Before it does this, though, it checks to back sure that there's a valid session, and if there isn't then it just redirects to the login page.  This works fine when linking from within the ASP.Net site, but when I link to it from a local MSWord file, it apparently doesn't know there's a valid session (even though I've logged in in the browser), and redirects to the login page.  Is there any way around this?  For compatibility these Word documents need to be in Word 97-2003 format unfortunately...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.  This won't work.

Opening the word file outside of a browser and clicking on the link is going to start a brand new session; regardless of whether you currently have a browser window opened on the site.

Because a new session is starting, the web server will assume you aren't logged in at all.  Which, technically, you aren't.

Comment: Thank you.  Any way around this other than not checking for a valid session?

Comment: I can see passing a parameter in the url of the link which then redirects to the document after the user is logged in, but this will be painful given that each Word document might have dozens of links to other documents or html files within the site, and they would have to re-log in every time, right?

Comment: I can't really see a way around this other than not checking for a "valid" session.  If they are starting off inside of word then they are pretty much in a "disconnected" state.